# Derived Class Calling static method of base class in its own static method

Tags: c#, static-methods, derived-class

I have read through the follow SO articles

- [C#: How do I call a static method of a base class from a static method of a derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603177/c-how-do-i-call-a-static-method-of-a-base-class-from-a-static-method-of-a-deri)
- [Can I have a base class where each derived class has its own copy of a static property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060124/can-i-have-a-base-class-where-each-derived-class-has-its-own-copy-of-a-static-pr)
- [What's the correct alternative to static method inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380087/whats-the-correct-alternative-to-static-method-inheritance-c)

All seem very close to my question and have good answers, but they do not seem to answer my question other than to say that I need to make the method non-static.

an example:

```
abstract public class baseClass
{
    private static List<string> attributeNames = new List(new string {"property1","property2"});
    // code for property definition and access
    virtual public static bool ValidAttribtue(string attributeName)
    {
        if (attributeNames.Contains(attributeName))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
class derivedA : baseClass
{
    private static List<string> attributeNames = new List(new string {"property3","property4"});
    // code for property definition and access
    public static override bool ValidAttribute(string attributeName)
    {
        if (attributeNames.Contains(attributeName))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ValidAttribute(attributeName);
        }
    }
}
class derivedB : baseClass
{
    private static List<string> attributeNames = new List(new string {"property10","property11"});
    // code for property definition and access
    public static override bool ValidAttribute(string attributeName)
    {
        if (attributeNames.Contains(attributeName))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ValidAttribute(attributeName);
        }
    }
}
```

derivedA would have properties 1,2,3,4 while derivedB would have properties 1,2,10,11.
The list of properties seems to be a class specific value and can not be changed at any point.  I would think it then would be static.

Is my design wrong in the sense that I am trying to use static methods when they should not be?

The above example makes me think that inheritance of static methods would be needed, yet it seems that trying to do this is a design flaw.  Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong with coding or structuring classes in this manner?

Comment: Is this actual code?  You can't have virtual static members.

Comment: No it is just example code of an operation that I was thinking should be possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is my design wrong in the sense that I am trying to use static methods when they should not be?

Yes. Aside from anything else, you're trying to declare a static method as `virtual` (and then override it), which isn't allowed. You're also trying to declare a class called `base`, when that's a keyword.

Static methods simply aren't polymorphic. The basis of polymorphism is that the execution time type of the instance involved can be different to the compile-time type of the expression, and the implementation is chosen on the basis of the execution time type. That concept doesn't make sense for static methods as there *is* no instance.

Now of course you *can* make a static method in a derived class call a static method in the base class - but there won't be any polymorphism anywhere.

As a side note, all of your methods could be written in a more readable way:

```
// Base class implementation
return attributeNames.Contains(attributeName);

// Derived class implementations
return attributeNames.Contains(attributeName) ||
       BaseClass.ValidAttribute(attributeName);
```

Comment: To make sure I am understanding this correctly, the abstract class defines the operation that all derived classes will have.  The derived classes need the functionality that is there.  The checking does not change ever and is completely defined at compile time.  The presence or absence of a property is known at compile time.  The checking needs to change per class but should be able to take advantage of the base classes function.  This building on each other is not a static mechanism but instead a polymorphism mechanism?

Comment: @JohnGroman: If you don't *need* polymorphism - i.e. calling on the "right" implementation at execution time based on the type of an instance - then you can do this without polymorphism. I would strongly advise you to give the methods different names to make it clearer that there really *isn't* any polymorphism going on, but it will work, in terms of a derived class's static method calling a base class's static method. It's just another static method, as far as the language is concerned - there's no relationship between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments I guess I need to read up more on polymorphism.  Also thanks for the more readable form